# One way swap for vectors, is it possible?

Tags: c++, stl, swap

In C++98, this is what I want to do (this does not work as _M_start, etc are private members):

```
void vectormove(std::vector<int>& a, std::vector<int>& b)
{
    a._M_impl._M_start = b._M_impl._M_start;
    a._M_impl._M_finish = b._M_impl._M_finish;
    a._M_impl._M_end_of_storage = b._M_impl._M_end_of_storage;
}
```

This is how I want to call

```
//vectors are predefined already
std::vector<int> a;
std::vector<int> b(10000000,20);

//in later part of code
//a=b;  //expensive copy
//std::swap(a,b);   //inexpensive swap
vectormove(a,b);  //i need an inexpensive one way swap instead
```

I may have butchered terminology by using copy, move and swap loosely, but I dont have a better grasp on this subject.  I hope I was able to convey my intent.

Comment: Why would you need two vectors referencing the same data, and how would you manage that?

Comment: Does [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) not do what you're looking for?

Comment: Vectors own their memory so there is no such thing as a "one way swap".  If this was possible it would cause double delete and possible heap corruption.

Comment: @computerfreaker OP requested a C++98 solution.

Comment: Make `a` a pointer or reference to `b`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: vectors are predefined and cannot be changed.

Comment: @beginner101: Then you're out of luck. Unless you're not describing your problem correctly. One question. After this hypothetical operation, what do you plan to do with `b`?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley:  In someplaces, I do not need "b" at all.  So swap is OK.  In other places, I go on to modify "b" further and assign it to some third vector "c". In this case swap is not OK, so I use a=b, before messing with "b"

Comment: @beginner101: Then forget it. You're basically asking for magic. Or, in some places do one thing, and in other places do a different thing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just want `a` to *refer* to `b`'s internals. The way to do that is just:

```
std::vector<int>& a = b;
```

if you want `a` to *take over* `b`'s internals, that's:

```
std::vector<int> a = std::move(b);
```

which in C++03 could be implemented as a swap with an empty vector:

```
std::vector<int> a;
using std::swap;
swap(a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to write a compilable implementation of your `vectormove()`, it's like this:

```
// NOT USEFUL CODE
void vectormove(std::vector<int>& a, std::vector<int>& b)
{
    memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof(std::vector<int>));
}
```

But this is not useful, because once you've done this you are on the path to undefined behavior.  Perhaps double-free, perhaps use-after-free, etc.

It seems like you would be best served either by the regular `a.swap(b)` or by storing `a` as type `int*` instead, like this:

```
std::vector<int> b(10000000,20);
std::pair<int*, int*> a(&b[0], &b[b.size()]);
```

Now you have an `a` which can be passed around cheaply and refers to the original vector.  Just make sure you don't invalidate `a` by modifying `b` afterwards.